# Identity Server 4 redirecting to development URL not production

Tags: identityserver4, appsettings, azure-appservice

I'm experiencing a weird situation with IDS4.

I have a Blazor WA app, and API, and IDS4. The Blazor and API are hooked into IDS4 and everything works for the most part. You click login in Blazor and it sends you to IDS4 where you authenticate and it sends you back to Blazor and then you can hit the API. All good.

Except when you register. Blazor takes your info and generates a registration email. The user clicks on the link which calls a method in the API that verifies the token, etc etc, and then sends you to IDS4 login. When the user logs in here, instead of sending you to the production Blazor URL, its it sending it to the development URL and I have no idea how it even knows what the dev url is. This happens on any machine not just my dev workstation. This is the appsettings.json.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=xxxxx;Database=xxxxxx;User Id=xxxxx;Password=xxxxxx"
},
"ClientURLs": {
"BlazorWA": "https://prodURL.azurewebsites.net/"
},
"IdentityServer": {
"Clients": [
  {
    "AllowOfflineAccess": true,
    "AllowedCorsOrigins": "*",
    "Enabled": true,
    "RequireConsent": false,
    "RequireClientSecret": false,
    "RequirePkce": true,
    "ClientId": "blazorWA",
    "ClientName": "blazorWA",
    "ClientUri": "https://prodURL.azurewebsites.net/",
    "RedirectUris": [ "https://prodURL.azurewebsites.net/authentication/login-callback" ],
    "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "authorization_code" ],
    "AllowedScopes": [ "openid", "profile", "email", "appAPI" ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [ "https://prodURL.azurewebsites.net/" ]
  }
  ]
}
```

Somehow, and only from the registration path, when the user clicks Login it attempts to go to "https://devURL...."

The only thing I can think of is somehow it is reading the appsettings.Development.json? Is that possible its getting published? But why would it work sometimes?

Thanks.

Comment: This is deployed to Azure btw.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the actual issue was, but having the feeling there was a file in Azure with the development settings, I went to my Publish settings and under 'File Publish Options' I checked 'Remove Additional Files At The Destination', which clears out anything not in the current set of files to be published and now it redirects to the proper URL.

¯_(ツ)_/¯